# RHEL 5 box constantly displaying NIC statistics on console screen, how can I disable this?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, rhel-5

I have a RHEL 5 box that is constantly displaying nic statistics on the console screen when using the KVM. This makes it very hard to do any troubleshooting when the box goes down as these statistics are scrolling through the screen during the login prompt, shutdown, boot up after the nic is enabled, and when using the system. Any ideas on what might be causing this to happen? This is the only box I see this happening on. This boxes also has zero third party software installed. This is just a base RHEL install.

Comment: What does exactly mean the _nic statistics_? Could you paste an example? Is it something like `netstat -i` prints? You said that it happens _ when using the KVM_. Does it mean that the statistics are printed on guest console or on the host console?